# Kernel source place in Buildroot

Tags: buildroot

I am new in Buildroot. I have linux kernel sources for P2041RDB NXP board, so where I should to place it and how to set this location in configuration?

Answer (score 9):

There is currently no way to set the path to the kernel source from the Buildroot configuration.

You have two options to do it.

1. Create a file `local.mk` in the directory that contains `.config` (i.e. the Buildroot source directory if you don't use the `O=` option, or the output directory if you do use `O=`). In `local.mk`, add a line with `LINUX_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR=` and fill in the path to the kernel source (either an absolute path, or a path relative to the Buildroot source directory).
2. Create a tarball of the kernel source. In the Buildroot configuration menu, under "Kernel", set "Kernel version" to "Custom tarball". Then set "URL of custom kernel tarball" to the file-URL, so `file:///path/to/the/tarball.tar.gz`.

Obviously, in either case, you need to enable the kernel build ("Linux kernel" option in the Kernel menu) and also set the other kernel options (kernel config, device tree, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

using local.mk works, BUT you need to also include 
`LINUX_HEADERS_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR =` in the `local.mk` file if you're building the cross compiler as well...