# buildroot/output/build/linux-custom/.stamp_built] Error 2 error in Buildroot

Tags: buildroot

I and newbie to using Buildroot system.

I have a local kernel source directory present on developement system which i am using in Buildroot but the build fails with following error.

```
package/pkg-generic.mk:290: recipe for target '/home/lsys/workspace/BuildrootWork/buildroot/output/build/linux-custom/.stamp_built' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/lsys/workspace/BuildrootWork/buildroot/output/build/linux-custom/.stamp_built] Error 2
Makefile:84: recipe for target '_all' failed
make: *** [_all] Error 2
```

Using the `LINUX_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR="/home/lsys/workspace/BuildrootWork/kernelsource/KERNEL_3_8"` i have given the path of the local kernel source directory in local.mk in Builroot directory where .config is present.

The build sucesfully works if i don't provide an override directory and kernel v5.10 builds fine.

Buildroot version : buildroot-2022.11.tar.gz from buildroot.org

override Linux kernel version : v3.8.x

board config used : config/beaglebone_defconfig

Comment: "*I have a local kernel source directory ...*" and "*Using the `LINUX_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR= `*" -- Provide the actual information for us to evaluate, instead of your vague, incomplete descriptions. Where did you put this `LINUX_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR= ...`? Study https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706633/kernel-source-place-in-buildroot

Comment: Have you tried `make linux-rebuild all`?

Comment: This LINUX_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR= is present in local.mk file in Buildroot directory where .config is present. Yes after making thses changes i did make linux-rebuild all