# Kernel linux source code with Buildroot make menuconfig

Tags: linux, kernel, embedded-linux, buildroot

I am new in "buildroot" I want to make an image for a VMware machine to run kernel Linux.

I have downloaded the Linux source code from: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/ and I did compile the source code.

I was wondering how I can attach the source code of Linux to the buildroot. I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54762211 Which tells you to make a "local.mk" and write LINUX_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR= and write the path inside.

My problem is: in the "make menuconfig" command in the kernel section what option I choose In the kernel version because I want to make an Image for my source code already compiled in my computer

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: there version returned when you do `make kernelversion` in your kernel tree.

Comment: @droptop what do you mean? , I have a Folder with the compiled source code and I did make the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54762211 in local.mk but what i write in the Kernel Version in this menuconfig?

Comment: You cannot use pre-compiled kernel in buildroot. Specify tarball path or URL to download kernel sources from, and let buildroot compile it.

Comment: @dimich no problem, I will not compile it but in the Linux kernel-> kernel version what do I need to choose?

Comment: @ATB "Custom tarball" and then specify path to tarball in "URL of custom kernel tarball". Also you can select "Custom [Git|Mercurial|Subversion} repository" and below specify repository to fetch sources from.

Comment: @ATB - learn to use the built-in `Help` of Buildroot to get an explanation of the configuration option, e.g. how to specify a *local* tarball.

Comment: @dimich Great Thanks, now I have bzImage how I can Insert it into  VMware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [the manual, "Customizing the generated target filesystem"](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rootfs-custom), there are two good ways to include an externally-built file in your Buildroot build. It doesn't matter here if it's a kernel image or anything else.

- Root filesystem overlays (BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY)
- Post-build scripts (BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT)

Refer to the manual for more details on how to use them. In your case, a post-build script that copies from the kernel build directory to `${TARGET_DIR}/boot` is probably the easiest.